# Meteor retrieving data from multiple docs

Tags: meteor

I have two collections in my Meteor app (Customers, Projects) as shown below, I am trying to join customer.name based on the customer_id saved in the Project document but can't find how to do so. So can someone please help by suggesting how I can do so? Thanks

```
Project {_id: "S83NEGHnrefvfASrf", title: "Meteor App 01", customerid: "QDGvBQhS6vYgZtnRr", duedate: "11/15/2014 11:42 PM"}

Customer {_id: "QDGvBQhS6vYgZtnRr", name: "Mary"}
```

projectslist.js:

```
Template.projectslist.helpers({
    projectsList: function () {
        return Projects.find({},{sort: {title: 1}});
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have

```
{{#each projectsList}}
{{name}}
{{/each}}
```

helper should look like this

```
name: function(){
   return Customer.findOne({_id:this.customerid}).name;
},
```